# How to make a stacked column graph in R using ggplot and with a matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi everybody I am trying to make a graphic in R with a matrix and using `ggplot` package due to R and ggplot give you awesome quality in elements related to graphs. I have a matrix of dim 20x20 and I am trying to get something like this:

[image]

I don't like to use excel due to its quality in graphics and because I prefer R but I don't have enough knowledge about ggplot, also I don't know how to add the last value in the matrix to the last column of the matrix. Maybe could you help me to solve this. The `dput` version of the matrix I am trying to plot is the next:

```
structure(c(29965719.12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28429960.41, 1458624.41, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26906565.89, 1440212.75, 
942099.599999998, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 25313701.12, 1401632.04, 927322.780000001, 1210951.2, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23748204.59, 1373259.46, 
909312.66, 1193709.88, 1151423.89, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22257069.98, 1341041.19, 889758.559999999, 
1158986.03, 1136820.61, 1598355.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20834214.97, 1305131.98, 856701.27, 1129474.09, 
1118606.69, 1578059.2, 1370856.78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 19477094.16, 1263379.53, 837751.299999997, 1104522.4, 
1092284.99, 1551142.64, 1354974.07, 1420547.36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18165404.24, 1221357.6, 817402.140000001, 
1075676.58, 1071100.22, 1485230.97, 1318482.08, 1404038.55, 2048291.06, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17042526.26, 1183285.92, 799139.77, 
1051973.84, 1049700.79, 1444005.64, 1279183.6, 1384857.86, 2026632.72, 
3043637.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15912055.89, 1150968.29, 
781767.969999999, 1027713, 1002821.26, 1416093.1, 1256348.38, 
1363220.55, 1995025.71, 3008201.12, 3669634.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 14837392.5, 1105477.16, 750258.4, 989174.439999999, 
979742.510000002, 1386614.86, 1231738.64, 1338049.47, 1960531.5, 
2930963.13, 3639935.05, 3641665.16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13717721.37, 
1063604.11, 730910.129999999, 946145.08, 956427.08, 1356840.33, 
1188091.57, 1314698.33, 1919815.43, 2872918.27, 3587264.2, 3615734.97, 
6780879.37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12654080.83, 1034304.47, 689927.319999998, 
920539.020000001, 933540.619999999, 1312891.36, 1157533.56, 1273552.45, 
1883854.01, 2803699.4, 3508212.44, 3571759.54, 6728597.15, 6229245.09, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11623390.05, 1007888.98, 671467.57, 875067.23, 
913815.460000001, 1222912.77, 1121345.7, 1218532.12, 1832366.96, 
2745773.97, 3399847.15, 3502858.93, 6604774.94, 6134253.45, 5553163.01, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10659885.1, 964108.52, 635246.380000001, 821454.51, 
885128.07, 1190048.79, 1090649.63, 1150376.15, 1783257.07, 2686616.54, 
3335146.8, 3406715.11, 6488674.75, 6014729.55, 5485803.42, 6372919.9, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 9735488.55, 938546.67, 607981.76, 786120.049999999, 
851119.98, 1162842.77, 1065054.88, 1073775.55, 1736231.45, 2614978.56, 
3271501.27, 3349167.83, 6368469.75, 5898741.78, 5418299.67, 6280598.84, 
6755054.64, 0, 0, 0, 8742383.48, 906474.289999999, 580510.6, 
755660.540000001, 829922.970000001, 1131575.38, 1039617.08, 1049134.57, 
1664696.67, 2552889.11, 3198760.39, 3264617.28, 6150581.39, 5627038.38, 
5316228.57, 6146363.09, 6677651.36, 7119008.27, 0, 0, 7882239.43, 
878026.84, 552812.210000001, 733031.09, 792261.039999999, 1097934.62, 
1014999.39, 1026214.95, 1630375.43, 2466505.47, 3145005.28, 3174913.27, 
6021366.2, 5462369, 5197168.91, 6012867.57, 6528649.55999999, 
7026048.51000001, 7585411.87, 0, 7116387.62, 850380.98, 499167.210000001, 
698711.68, 716107.529999999, 1070802.59, 981550.33, 977666.770000001, 
1595348.57, 2405959.16, 3084197.92, 3104095.11, 5928707.85, 5445385.54, 
5114034.19, 5886576.44000001, 6421200.57, 6749735.19, 7492647.16, 
7402737.51000001), .Dim = c(20L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(c("ene 10", 
"feb 10", "mar 10", "abr 10", "may 10", "jun 10", "jul 10", "ago 10", 
"sep 10", "oct 10", "nov 10", "dic 10", "ene 11", "feb 11", "mar 11", 
"abr 11", "may 11", "jun 11", "jul 11", "ago 11"), c("ene 10", 
"feb 10", "mar 10", "abr 10", "may 10", "jun 10", "jul 10", "ago 10", 
"sep 10", "oct 10", "nov 10", "dic 10", "ene 11", "feb 11", "mar 11", 
"abr 11", "may 11", "jun 11", "jul 11", "ago 11")))
```

Thanks a lot of for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the data needs to be transformed into the long format, i.e., one value per row. This is easy with the `reshape2` package:

```
library(reshape2)
dat2 <- melt(dat)
```

where `dat` is the name of your matrix.

By default, R will order factor levels alphabetically. The next command restores the original order:

```
dat2 <- transform(dat2, X1 = factor(X1, colnames(dat)),
                        X2 = factor(X2, rownames(dat)))
```

Calculate the the sum of the values in the last column of `dat`:

```
finalVal <- sum(dat[ , ncol(dat)])
```

Now, the new data frame `dat2` can be plotted. The function `annotate` is used to display the text above the last bar.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat2, aes(x = X2, y = value, fill = X1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  annotate("text", x = ncol(dat) - .5, y = finalVal + 2000000, 
           label = finalVal, size = 3)
```

The arguments `x` and `y` of `annotate` allow defining the position of the text. In the above code, I used `- .5` and `+ 2000000` to fine-tune the position.

[image]

Comment: Thanks dear @SvenHohenstein and Is it possible to add in the final column of the plot the last number in the matrix?? In the case my matrix would have more rows and cols for example 80x80 matrix the legend will include all labels or I have to change any parameters to display it with all labels.

Comment: Oh thanks dear @SvenHohenstein and final little question is it possible to add for example in the last column of plot the sum of all values considered for that column instead of the final value for that column in the plot.

Comment: @Duck The displayed value is the sum, not the last value.

Comment: Oh sorry @SvenHohenstein I don't see it clearly that is awesome, and I am supossed it is difficult to set in plot only the final value, I saw in the basic R graphs and they make this It would be possible to put over the total only the final value that would be fantastic and thanks for your help!

Comment: @Duck In the code, you can see, how `annotate` works. You can add another `+ annotate(..., label = dat[nrow(dat), ncol(dat)]`. Use the `annotate` as a basis to play around with the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

please use d3.js library for the interactive graphs.it will give you the api for making many types of graphs with good use of customization acordng to your need.